# How to apply OR in PrincipalPermission in base and derive class

Tags: c#, security, role-base-authorization, genericprincipal

I have a base class.

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Admin")]
public class Base
{

}
```

and derived one.

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Developer")]
public class Derived : Base
{

}
```

I want to let user with "Developer" rights to create an object of Derived. But I am unable to do as base class has permission to admin.

Admin should be able to create object of all derived classes. So I want to put the permission in base class for admin.

How can I sort this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that this doesn't work is that the `Base` class is created before the `Derived` class. And as only administrators can call the `Base` class you have no way of letting the `Role=Developer` create the base object.

You could however introduce 2 constructors in this scenario in the base class, one restricted to `Admin` and possibly a protected one restricted to the `Developer`. You'd then have to call the c'tor for the `Developer` explicitly from the `Derived` class.

However, I really would NOT recommend doing this. I'd rather introduce a factory class or method and restrict the creation there.