# Using different PrincipalPermissions in an overridden method

Tags: c#, wcf, overriding

I have a `DeleteAll` method in my base class that requires a specific role ("Remover") to be called.  I have a second class that derives from the base class.  In the derived class, I want to override the `DeleteAll` method so I can require a different role ("Operator") to the method.

```
public BaseClass
{
    [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Authenticated = true, Role = "Remover")]
    public virtual void DeleteAll(IEnumerable<Guid> ids)
    {
        //Code to delete each id
    }
}

public DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Authenticated = true, Role = "Operator")]
    public virtual void DeleteAll(IEnumerable<Guid> ids)
    {
        base.DeleteAll(ids);
    }
}
```

If I call `DerivedClass`'s `DeleteAll` method, it will require a user to have *both* the "Operator" and the "Remover" roles.  I only want the "Operator" role to be required.

Is there a way to override PrincipalPermission when overriding a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using the `baseclass` in the `derivedclass`, so the `DeleteAll` method resulting in `DerivedClass` needs to have both "operator" and "deleter" roles.
You can try combining multiple PrincipalPermissionAttribute requirements using OR.
See the link below for details.
[PrincipalPermission on Method doesn't work if applied to Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50707172/principalpermission-on-method-doesnt-work-if-applied-to-class)

 [How to apply OR in PrincipalPermission in base and derive class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064284/how-to-apply-or-in-principalpermission-in-base-and-derive-class)